# Copyright for model in blender

Tags: rendering

I've seen tutorials in sculpting/modelling famous actors (Hugh Laurie, etc). But, I suppose, those ones were created for non-commercial use. I wonder if I have rights to sell (commercial use) my blend file with famous actor model in it? Lets also say he/she says a famous movie "quote"?

I'm familiar with [the question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/can-i-use-images-rendered-with-blender-for-commercial-use) and its answer by David. But it did not include details about having right over models of real things that may already have copyright on it (famous actors, quotes [for animation], iPhones, iPad models...).

And could you please refer to scource (article or law quote), if any, to support your answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, I've voted to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about law and therefore outside the scope of Blender Stack Exchange. Furthermore, there may not be a single answer to the question because the answer may depend upon who the depicted persons are, where they are domiciled (for legal purposes), and where the models are made. For example the answer for a model of a scene including an actor domiciled in the UK made by an American and marketed in the US may be different than the same model made by someone in the UK.

Comment: This question does not belong on Blender.SE as it is about Copyright Law and not about the software package.

Comment: You might want to try [law.stackexchange.com](http://law.stackexchange.com/)