# Can I upload / share my Blender animations?

Tags: objects, licensing

Am I free to upload/distribute my final rendered Blender animations (without the use of external textures)?

What license restrictions (if any) are there on artwork produced by Blender and what attribution must I, for example, place in the description?

If possible quote a source from Blender.org because I find there nothing.

Comment: Hi. This is a forum for Blender specific questions.  If you are having problems uploading your finished render to a website you may have more luck asking for assistance elsewhere.  If you have a Blender specific question, please clarify what your problem is.

Comment: No, I know how to be export a video file / upload my video. My question is whether the videos can easily upload as, or a license needs?

Comment: @ChristopherJoost Does this answer your question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/can-i-use-images-rendered-with-blender-for-commercial-use

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal aspects that are not really related to blender, but copyright law.  A site like http://law.stackexchange.com/ or http://opensource.stackexchange.com/ would be more suited for this issues.

Comment: read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic/423#423

Answer (score 1):

The copyright on artwork created with Blender is owned by the creator of the artwork.  Nothing in the [Blender license agreement](https://www.blender.org/about/license/) infringes on the moral rights of the artist.

This means you are free to publish, distribute, licence, exhibit or otherwise diseminate your art as you see fit.

See the *Your Artwork* section of Blender license page:

> All your artwork – images or movie files – including the .blend files
>   and other data files Blender can write, is free for you to use as you
>   like.
>
> That means that Blender can be used commercially by artists, by
>   studios to make animation films or vfx, by game artists to work on
>   commercial games, by scientists for research, and by students in
>   educational institutions.