# Commerical usage

Tags: modeling, licensing

I’m part of a company that has engineers who need to use 3d modeling software and print the designs out!

I’m having troubles finding a commercial license in order to design, and print out a model from scratch.

Google SketchUp wants 695 dollars, and the alternatives lead me to Blender.

Can I use Blender for commercial use?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12332/16395, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50921/16395

Answer (score 3):

#### Blender is free software and you can freely use it for commercial purposes.

Also, the artwork and files you create with Blender remain your own intellectual property.

You are only bound to licensing clauses when you modify Blender itself and want to redistribute a modified copy of the software. In that case, you need to make sure that your new distribution shares the same license as the original software. However, this doesn't seem to be your case.

You can find more here: https://www.blender.org/about/license/